# Changing the color set into a method when a jbutton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-color

```
        private void btn_productManagementMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
        setColor(btn_productManagement);
        resetColor(btn_accounts);
        resetColor(btn_priceChecker);
        resetColor(btn_settings);
        resetColor(btn_signout);
        
        jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        
    } 


    void setColor(JPanel panel){
         panel.setBackground(new Color(78,50,137));
                
    }
    
    void resetColor(JPanel panel){
        panel.setBackground(new Color(63,43,100));
                
    }
```

I have this GUI made from netbeans where I used a jlabel as my tab selector and this code handles the switching color or highlighting of the labels depending on the panel that is selected. I made a setting where you set a specific theme for the whole GUI and Im wondering how can I manipulate the code inside of the setColor and resetColor method and change the color that is set with each methods. I'll leave a picture for visualization. Thanks!

## Here's the tab section

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKpJP.png]

Comment: You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
The image actually looks like you could (or should?) have a `JList` or similar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.